# How to add page navigation slide transition effect in single page application

Tags: javascript, html, css

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <div id="Header"></div> // Static Header
 <div id="Main"></div> // Dynamic pages will be loaded
 <div id="Footer"></div>// Static Footer
</body>
```

Here in "Main" i will be pushing new pages. Currently when i push new page to "Main" the new page suddenly appears which is obvious since i didn't add any transition.

My requirements are

1. when I push new page to "Main" the first page should slide to left and the new page should slide from right to center of the screen.
2. If I click back from 2nd page then 2nd page should slide to right and first page should slide from left to center.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the code you have so far, and specific problems you are having.  It seems from your post you haven't started and you are possibly looking for someone to write all the code to get you a working demo based on your requirements .  That isn't quite how q&a forum works

Comment: Have you tried creating two sub divs inside main, one for the current page and one for the next page? You can fill the next-page div and use css or js to move them both to the left

Comment: @Scott Selby Already I have completed coding and created full fledged web application. Only transition effect is pending. So i explained my project in short. BTW I don't need any one to write full code for me, just I need some approaches to handle this. FYI, we can definitely share various approaches to achieve a functionality in forum. Thanks for your valuable time and reply☺

Comment: @ user2786485 : This approach sounds good. Then actually need to maintain prev,current and next page in 3 different divs to have next page and previous page transition effect. Thank you ☺ will try your approach ☺